# How to set variable cell spacing for cells in UICollectionView

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView with custom cells and I want to have different spacing between each of these cells. Using minimumlinespacing, it affects all the cells. Is there anyway to specifically change the spacing between 2 specific cells? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to solve this.

1. You can use [sizeForCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview) method to resize your specific cell according to indexPath
2. You can create two cells: one for more spacing, second with compact spacing and call **dequqeResuseableCell** accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't these ways just change the size of the cell and not the space in between the cell? I am able to get different cell sizes correctly, but I would like certain cells to be closer to each other, and others farther.